# Maximum Length of Command Line String

Tags: windows, command-line

In Windows, what is the maximum length of a command line string? Meaning if I specify a program which takes arguments on the command line such as `abc.exe -name=abc`

A simple console application I wrote takes parameters via command line and I want to know what is the maximum allowable amount.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I've been working on [a way for programs to support longer command lines](https://github.com/al45tair/ArgX).  Assuming we can build enough support for it, this would remove the restrictions completely without requiring Microsoft to fix anything, and in a manner that is straightforwardly compatible. Not really an answer to the question, but worth having a link here IMO.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From the Microsoft documentation: [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation)

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters.

Comment: This only applies to the programs actually run through the command prompt (per the question). Shortcuts (.lnk) are limited to 260 characters, CreateProcess to 32767, and ShellExecute to about 2048. [According to Raymond Chen's article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx)

Comment: 2^13-1 characters, that implies something is tracked in a 16 number and this uses 13 of those bits. I wonder what the other 3 bits are for?

Comment: @ulrichb And now that link is broken too after yet another blog migration.  The cited article can now be found at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553

Comment: How long is the limit now with Windows 11 and the new Windows Terminal? 
I hope they increased it. Passing tens of thousands files with long paths to CMake is taking megabytes. Should be unlimited.

Answer (score 76):

Sorry for digging out an old thread, but I think [sunetos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205048/124119) isn't correct (or isn't the full answer). I've done some experiments (using ProcessStartInfo in c#) and it seems that the 'arguments' string for a commandline command is limited to 2048 characters in XP and 32768 characters in Win7. I'm not sure what the 8191 limit refers to, but I haven't found any evidence of it yet.

Comment: Where'd you get the 32k figure for Win7? I can't find a source for that. Are you thinking of [the size of the environment block](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/03/9957320.aspx)?

Comment: Possibly. I found the 32k figure by passing longer and longer arguments to a process via C# ProcessStartInfo class. It throws an exception after 32k.

Comment: @LordTorgamus, The 32k limit is due to the [UNICODE_STRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (ushort length). [According to Raymond Chen's article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx) CMD limits lines to 8192 characters (I'd assume the carrage return is the final character) and ShellExecuteEx limits to "INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH (around 2048)"

Comment: Definitely more like a 32k limit for me on Windows 7

Comment: What about under PowerShell on Windows 10?

Comment: 8191 for cmd and the likes seems very real, just ran into this when running a very long command via Exec in MSBuild

Comment: Big evidence for a 8191 limit: paste any command into a DOS prompt under Windows 10 x64, and it truncates it to 8191 characters. Your answer is incorrect enough to be misleading.

Comment: @Contango  have you tried WinTerminal instead of cmd.exe. 
I hope it can't be still that limited.

Comment: @lothar cmd.exe is a command shell, not a terminal. The window that pops up when you start cmd.exe from the Run dialog is, as I understand it, actually displayed by conhost.exe, which is actually built from the same codebase as Windows Terminal these days. (These console windows used to be hosted by csrss.exe; I believe that code was migrated to conhost.exe in Windows 7 to make copy&paste/drag&drop play well with UAC? And I have no idea how it worked in 9x.)  But anyway, cmd.exe is actually just the command shell or interpreter, and running it under Windows Terminal won't change buffer size.

Comment: @SamB  Well it has neither to do with WinTerminal or cmd.exe but depends on kernel settings and the windows subsystem settings (dos/command line, windows app or posix apps) which also selects if conhost is started or not. 

I know that the kernel is not limited anymore to  8192 bytes because the path length is no by default upto 32768 bytes long and therefore the ARG[0] could already overflow this arguments space. 

Agile Microsoft likes to improve programs now in updates. And i'm sure that with the development of winterm they also touched cmd.com.

Answer (score 53):

As @Sugrue I'm also digging out an old thread.

To explain why there is 32768 (I think it should be 32767, but lets believe experimental testing result) characters limitation we need to dig into Windows API.

No matter how you launch program with command line arguments it goes to [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or any extended their version. These APIs basically wrap other NT level API that are not officially documented. As far as I know these calls wrap [NtCreateProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/nt%20objects/process/ntcreateprocess.html), which requires [OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure as a parameter, to create that structure [InitializeObjectAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used. In this place we see `UNICODE_STRING`. So now lets take a look into this structure:

```
typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING;
```

It uses `USHORT` (16-bit length [0; 65535]) variable to store length. And according [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), length indicates size in bytes, not characters. So we have: `65535 / 2 = 32767` (because `WCHAR` is 2 bytes long).

There are a few steps to dig into this number, but I hope it is clear.

---

Also, to support @sunetos answer what is accepted. 8191 is a maximum number allowed to be entered into `cmd.exe`, if you exceed this limit, `The input line is too long.` error is generated. So, answer is correct despite the fact that `cmd.exe` is not the only way to pass arguments for new process.

Comment: The length is up to 32,766 characters because a null-terminated string is stored.

Comment: Processes aren't named in the object namespace, so the `ObjectAttributes` is only used for the security descriptor and making the returned handle inheritable. The command line is passed in the `ProcessParameters`, which is referenced by the Process Environment Block (PEB). With the old `NtCreateProcess`, these parameters have to be written to the child process via `NtWriteVirtualMemory`. Nowadays `NtCreateUserProcess` is used, which combines several calls to a single kernel service -- e.g. creating `Section`, `Process`, and `Thread` objects; and writing the process parameters.

Comment: @eryksun The **UNICODE_STRING** structure does not necessarily store null terminator.

Comment: @賈可Jacky, obviously a counted string does not necessarily use a null-terminated string. For example, with the NTAPI registry functions we can create and access key names with nulls in them, but they won't be accessible with WINAPI registry functions, which use null-terminated strings. Likewise, WINAPI `CreateProcessW` uses a null-terminated string for the command line and application path. The limit is 32,767 - 1, i.e. 32,766 characters.

Comment: @eryksun I found that the document about **Registry Element Size Limits** on MSDN said that the maximum length of a registry key name is 255 characters, but actually you may create a key name of 256 characters. Since the C-style string is just a pointer without length limit, so I guess that it may be possible to pass a string of 32,767 characters to the unicode function `CreateProcessW`, it may store the exact length in the `UNICODE_STRING` structure, and set both `Length` and `MaximumLength` to 65,534, it is a legal argument for `NtCreateProcess`.

Comment: @賈可Jacky, why guess instead of writing a quick program to test this? It's what I originally did. A command line with 32,767 characters fails with `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE` (206). This comes from an internal call to `RtlInitUnicodeStringEx` (NT 5.2+), which requires that the initializing string is a null-terminated string that's no longer than `UNICODE_STRING_MAX_CHARS - 1`, i.e. 32,766 characters. Older Windows versions called `RtlInitUnicodeString`, which naively assumes the length is valid and returns nonsense if not, such as `Length == 32767` and `MaximumLength == 0` (overflow).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! I have never tested it.

Comment: Are these numbers including path to the executable, or only applied the command line arguments?

Answer (score 9):

In Windows 10, it's still 8191 characters...at least on my machine.

It just cuts off any text after 8191 characters. Well, actually, I got 8196 characters, and after 8196, then it just won't let me type any more.

Here's a script that will test how long of a statement you can use. Well, assuming you have gawk/awk installed.

```
echo rem this is a test of how long of a line that a .cmd script can generate >testbat.bat
gawk 'BEGIN {printf "echo -----";for (i=10;i^<=100000;i +=10) printf "%%06d----",i;print;print "pause";}' >>testbat.bat
testbat.bat
```

Comment: That's the limit for cmd.exe. As the answer above says, the actual limit is 32,768 characters because of UNICODE_STRING.

Comment: I also get the ~8k limit on both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 in cmd.exe.