# ENAMETOOLONG when using GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to use [GraphicsMagick](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) to create a sprite map, but it appears the command it creates is too long (it's over 43K chars).

What alternatives are there (in Node.js) for combining many images (various file formats) into one larger image? I need to position them at specific locations.

In case you were wondering, the command that ImageMagick generates looks like:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:transparent -page +0+0 icons\application_view_detail.png -page +16+0 icons\application_view_icons.png ... -page +96+496 icons\xhtml.png -page +112+496 icons\xhtml_add.png -mosaic output.png
```

I'm also using GM to read the width + height of each image, but that's pretty much all I need it for.

**Edit:** I should note that I'm on Windows. (8.1 specifically)

Comment: I have not used this particular npm in node, but this sounds like a portability issue where the npm doesn't read windows file paths properly. If you have any sample code, I can try running it on CentOS.

Comment: @Munim: I don't think its a pathing issue; it works on smaller data sets just fine. I believe it's due to the [maximum length of a command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9992329/65387).