# Batch File Droplet

Tags: batch-file

I have a droplet that uses imagemagick "convert" to compress multiple files that I drag and drop on to the droplet. I have scavanged the code from other sources online and don't really understand what it is doing. My problem is, I can only drag and drop 82 files at a time, any more and the script will not work.

Here is my code:

```
if not exist "%~p1output\"NUL mkdir "%~p1output\"
:nextFile
   if "%~1" equ "" goto exitLoop
   convert "%~1"* -quality 70 "%~p1output\%~n1%~x1"
   shift
   goto nextFile
:exitLoop
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It gives any error after the 82th file?

Comment: No, it just terminates the script and doesn't process any of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch gets the dropped file names via command line. The length of the command line is limited to [8191 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205048/2098699). So I think more than approx. 80 names exceeds the limit.

Comment: You can use a batch file with wildcards to process a folder full, or a branch of folders.

Comment: For drag and drop the limit is only 4096