# How to call powershell.exe with long arguments from Visual Studio External Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

From a Visual STudio external tool, I would like to call a powershell script like this :

> `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "{ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwerShell -EA 0; & ""C:\a very long path to my script with spaces\my-script.ps1"" -ProjectFile ""c:\another very long path\to my visual studio project file\of a \customerprojet.csproj"" -WebPartDefinition ""c:\another very long path\to my visual studio project file\of a\file-in-my-customerproject.xml"" }"`

Actually, I defined my external tools to use some tokens :

> `-command { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwerShell -EA 0; & ""C:\a very long path to my script with spaces\my-script.ps1"" -ProjectFile ""$(ProjectFileName)"" -WebPartDefinition ""$(ItemPath)"" }`

However, this command line exceed the 260 chars limits allowed by Windows, and it does not works. It seems the command line is truncated (missing `}` at the end of my command.

How can I solve this?

**[Edit]** Actually, there was an issue with the project file. The token `$(ProjectFileName)` does not include the project directory, so I have to put instead:

> `-command { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwerShell -EA 0; & """C:\a very long path to my script with spaces\my-script.ps1""" -ProjectFile ""$(ProjectFileName)\$(ProjectFileName)"" -WebPartDefinition ""$(ItemPath)"" }`

I also have to "triple" the quotes around the ps1 path (not understanding why though)

**But** this does not works. The argument is too long and visual studio forbid me to put this value.

**[Edit2]** To be sure of the syntax, here is how I call the script successfully from the command line :

> `powershell -command "& { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwerShell -EA 0; & """C:\path-to\myscript.ps1""" -ProjectFile """C:\Projects\someproject\someproject.csproj""" -WebPartDefinition """C:\Projects\someproject\somefolder\somefile.xml""" -Verbose }"`

Which can be tokenized as :

> `powershell -command "& { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwerShell -EA 0; & """C:\path-to\myscript.ps1""" -ProjectFile """$(ProjectFileName)\$(ProjectFileName)""" -WebPartDefinition """$(ItemPath)""" -Verbose }"`

But the command line is still too long with the real paths :(

Comment: Looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string) the command line accepts ~8K characters. Edit the question to add the error message you see, so we can make our own deductions

Comment: I may have misunderstood the issue. Please see my edit.

Comment: we use Triple quotes if we want to have a quote inside a string. You can also use grave accent quote instead of triple quote like this : 
`"\`"`

Comment: Are you trying to call powershell using MSBuild xml file? If yes, [Refer here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files) to see how you can format your command string.

Comment: No, I want to call a script from the external tools of Visual Studio. This is not part of build process, but a script that generates some code (and which is a bit long to process), and the script should scopes the current file

Comment: I created an echo.bat external tool, which just echos the args. I sent an 875 character long argument, and the batch file was invoked properly, and echoed the whole big argument string.

Comment: I tried this, which works, and pauses to see output :
`-command "& {  echo \`"Hi\`" } ; cmd /c pause | out-null"`

replace the echo slowly clause by clause with your complex command, and paste error wherever it fails to run. The above line goes into the arguments text box, and "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" goes into the Command TextBox

Comment: @Zasz: visual does not let me enter the full arguments in edit external tool dialog. The argument textbox has length restriction. Actually, when I paste my command line, it's truncated

Comment: based on my test, only the 151 first characters are kept in the visual studio dialog*

Comment: HAHA And in VS2013 it allows 250 chars. No solution except to create a shorter symlink to your script file. use mklink to create symlinks with shorter paths.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering a similar problem using Dr. Memory.

The Arguments field of External Tools only allows 250 characters (I needed 321).

I was able to workaround the issue by creating a batch file.  Perhaps you could pass the tokens as arguments to the batch file and then build the full command in the batch and call from there?