# "Bad file number" error for a very long command line

Tags: windows, bash

I have a particularly large java command to execute (lot's of parameters, long classpath, etc) - and when I run it like that (as I normally do in my Windows via git bash app, which tries to emulate linux bash):

```
java <classpath here> <params>
```

it returns me the weird message:
sh.exe": /c/Windows/system32/java: Bad file number

BUT, whenever I decrease the command length (by removing any part of it - classpath, params) to about 32k symbols - it runs ok.

Is there any length limit in Windows/bash/java to a single executed command ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string

Comment: @gawi thanks! so the limit in Win7 is 32768

Comment: Maybe this supports longer strings: http://cygwin.com/

Comment: For all Windows versions - https://www.google.com/#q=windows+command+line+maximum+length