# Why java executable doesn't accept parameter files?

Tags: java, javadoc, javac

Let's assume I would like to execute a Java application:

```
java -cp j1:j2...:j9999 Main arg1 arg2
```

In this case, the java executable gets a plethora of arguments which, on certain OSes, can cause problems due to the length limitation of the command line string (see [Maximum Length of Command Line String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205027/594406)).

As a remedy, `javac` offers the `@argfile` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile)) which allows specifying the arguments within a file. The above example would look like this, if `java` supported it as well:

```
java @FileContainingArguments.txt
```

and the content of `FileContainingArguments.txt` is:

```
-cp j1:j2...:j9999
Main
arg1
arg2
```

So the question is, why `java` doesn't support it, while `javac` and `javadoc` do?

Comment: If you're asking how to pass parameters to a compiled Java program, you don't need the `@` decorator and can pass them in by name: `java MyProgram data_file.txt`. If they're in a different folder, you can pass them in by path.

Comment: @wadda_wadda not really, i want to pass a very large `classpath`

Comment: There are libraries for dealing with command line options: apache **CLI** and **args4j**. You could contribute code for such a @-file inlining to them. I am not aware of any of them having that.

Comment: A classpath can be specified in a jar's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as `Class-Path: ...` and you may use directories of jars in the class path.

Comment: You question is too broad. If you want to pass huge classpath please ask about this specific problem

Comment: Please, think carefully about what you really want to know. Do you really want to know **why** that feature isn’t supported or do you want to know **whether** it is support or a workaround exists? If you find out that your written question doesn’t match your actual intentions, edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it is not supported yet, but it seems Open JDK 9 will support it, once it is released:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027634. I am not sure about Oracle.