# Python Winrm fail to execute long power shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell, powershell, winrm

I am using linux python winrm module to run powershell scripts from linux machine on remote windows machine using "run_ps".

It is working fine for small size of script but failing to execute if pass too long power shell code.

The "run_ps" method has following code.

```
def run_ps(self, script):
    """base64 encodes a Powershell script and executes the powershell
    encoded script command
    """

    # must use utf16 little endian on windows
    base64_script = base64.b64encode(script.encode("utf_16_le"))
    rs = self.run_cmd("powershell -encodedcommand %s" % (base64_script))
    if len(rs.std_err):
        # if there was an error message, clean it it up and make it human
        # readable
        rs.std_err = self.clean_error_msg(rs.std_err)
    return rs
```

I guess it may be "utf_16_le" encoding issue or bytes size issue but not sure. I have tried using "utf_32_le" but no results.

I am running script from CentOS release 6.2 (Final) using Python 2.6.6.

Linux Python Winrm module link: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it shows error message as <Response code 1, out "", err "The command line is too long.">

Comment: Seems to be a limitation of self.run_cmd, as the encoded command (base64_script) is a param to this function.

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea how fix this limit issue.

Comment: There are several Limits, regarding where the command comes from, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string

Comment: To work around, you could place your script locally at the target server and then run an invoke-command via the module.

Comment: No i dont want to place script on remote machine for security reason. I will check the link, thanks :)