# How to send http request to compiler

Tags: c#, php, http

I'm developing a web server in Csharp and I want to install php compiler on it.

Current state: the web server is working and receiving connection, can compile PHP pages, I'm invoking PHP compiler using `procces start` and I can send GET parameters as arg like that:

```
php.exe name=1 /index.php
```

The problem is how to send post, get data and HTTP headers to the compiler in such better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a rather hackish solution to pass HTTP headers on the command-line interface: The `-B` or [`--process-begin`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)  flag allows for code to be run before the script in question. This could be used to inject data into the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal array to simulate headers being set. E.g. for `X-Foo: bar` to be set, you would run this:

```
php.exe --process-begin '$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FOO"] = bar;' /index.php
```

The same can be done with the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals. However, this really is just a hack and I cannot recommend this outside of academic environments for security reasons.

A slightly better way were to take advantage of the [builtin webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). If you have coded cleanly enough, it should be no problem to reroute incoming requests to PHP and channel the result back. This will only work flawlessly if you do not require any virtualhosts, though. And as with the solution above, this has no place outside of research!

The absolute correct way were to implement the [Common Gateway Interface](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875). PHP comes with a CGI interface itself, so speaking CGI to it is [trivial](http://test.nizarium.com/phpcgi/). If you run into scalability problems, you may want to switch to [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). A sample implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/mzabani/FastCgiNet).

One last thing: PHP is an *interpreted* language, not a compiled one.

Comment: i appreciate your solution and i prefer the hackish to send data  and it is so helpful with get and post for  plaintext , what about multipart content 
i do not like to use more resources (built in server ) nor switching to fastcgi

Comment: If this is about file uploads, you can try injecting into the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal. For everything more complex (e.g. full-blown MIME multipart messages), this won't viable. Also keep in mind that the length of the command line is [limited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string). For these reasons - security above all - I *strongly* suggest adopting CGI or FastCGI.