# How many strings can I pass in String args[] as command line parameters in Java?

Tags: java, command-line, jvm, args

What is the maximum size of `String args[]` in Java?

More specifically, how many command line parameters (as String elements) can `args[]` accommodate - i.e. how many strings can I pass via the command line after `java Main`?

Like, `java main hi hello how r you I m fine`. What is the limit?

Comment: but also depends on OS (I think)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger is right, e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string

Comment: Yes, it is possible that the OS Command shell may impose limits, so the smaller of the JVM's limit and the OS Command shell would be right.

I think it's highly unlikely that any reasonable application command line should reach 64K

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE , comes around 2 billion

Comment: As it comes down to **C's main**: there is no limit specified. I would also advise to support in such a case the Unix convention of having args is a file, say `argsfile.txt`, and pass a parameter `@argsfile.txt`.