# How can I bypass the character limit of Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing math operations in Python 3.7. These math operations have digit strings of 10k+. When I copy and paste these digits strings into Python 3.7, they get cut off. Thus, I'm not able to do the math operations.

```
format(y,'o')

**Note:** “y” is a digit string of 10k+
```

Is there a way to bypass this character limit in Python 3.7?

**Note:** This is an issue of a string or character limitation. This is not an issue of handling large numbers. These issues positively correlate. But, they're still fundamentally different. Thus, this isn't a duplicate topic.

**edit 2:**

I got this to work thanks to Andrew F

```
if 1:
 from pathlib import Path
 y = Path(r"C:\Users\l\Desktop\y.txt").read_text()
 y = int(y)
 format(y,'o')

**note:** “y.txt” contains only the digit string
```

Comment: Since you're sure it's not a duplicate, have you tried reading from a file instead of copy-paste? the clipboard has limits too

Comment: 8191 characters limit for Windows - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string

Comment: @iAmTryingOK ? how do i get python to read this operation from a file

Comment: @Aran-Fey https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lgpapribpv4dus/python-limit.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I'd be surprised if it was the python interpreter's fault, though. It's probably some weird Windows behavior. Just to make sure, does it work if you open a terminal and start python in that terminal?

Comment: @Aran-Fey ·ya, it must be the 8191 char limit of windows · i wonder if getting python to read the operation from a file could bypass this limit · but i don't know how to get python to do this

Comment: Try reading it from a txt file. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are new lines in your string, you can paste it into the console as part of a block quote, using `"""` to mark the beginning and end. As long as each line is under the limit of your system's console (apparently Windows at ~8000) then you should be alright.

Edit: reading data from a file is more or less guaranteed to work, regardless of limitations of your system's console. You can do it with `pathlib` (part of the standard library in Python 3) or `pathlib2` if you're using python 2

```py
from pathlib import Path
y = Path('path/to/your/file.txt').read_text()
```

Edit 2: here is a complete example of how you can read this from a text file.

Suppose you have a gigantic number (e.g. a googol) and you put it in a text file named `gigantic-number.txt`. The contents of `gigantic-number.txt` look like

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Within a Python console, you can load the contents of that file and then cast it as an integer. Using the example from before with `pathlib`

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> # read the contents of the file as a string
>>> y = Path('gigantic-number.txt').read_text()
>>> # convert the string into an integer, this will fail unless it's actually a number
>>> y = int(y)
```

Some sources of gigantic numbers produce text files that contain line breaks in them. This makes them more readable in simple text editors like Notepad. One example is from [GIMPS](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/): [`M3217.txt`](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/digits/M3217.txt) looks like

```
2591170860132026277762467679224415309418188875531254273039749231618740192665863620862012095168004834
0655069524173319417744168950923880701741037770959751204231306662408291635351795231118615486226560454
7691127595848775610568757931191017711408826252153849035830401185072116424747461823031471398340229288
0745456779079410372882358207058923510684338829868886166586502809276920803396058693087905004095037098
7590211901837199162099400256893511313654882973911265679730324198651725011641270350970542777347797234
9821676443446668383119322540099648994051790241624056519054483690809616061625743042361721863339415852
4264312087372665919620617535357488928945996291951830826218608534009379328394202618665861425032514507
7309627423537682293864940712770084607712421182308080413929808705750471382526457144837937112503208182
6126566649084251699453951887789613650248405739378594599444335231188280123660406262468609212150349937
584782292237144339628858485938215738821232393687046160677362909315071
```

Building on the example from before, you can read this from a file, remove the whitespace, and *then* cast as an integer.

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from string import digits
>>> # read from file as a string
>>> y = Path('M3217.txt').read_text()
>>> # keep only digit characters and "."
>>> y = ''.join(digit for digit in y if digit in digits+".")
>>> # cast as an integer
>>> int(y)
259117086013202627776246767922441530941...
```

To be clear, *only the number goes in the text file*. Your edited question makes it seem like you pasted the Python code into the text file as well which is not going to solve this problem.

Comment: · i tried reading data from a file · it didn't work · i edited my post to show this · i've yet to try the block quote method though

Comment: · ah, i was missing y = int(y) · this was the problem · i got it to work now · thanks