# Any limits on cmd.exe command echo?

Tags: windows, cmd, echo

I'm using this piece of code to manipulate a txt file content:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /A count=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (a.txt) DO (
  ECHO !count! %%A
  ECHO %%A >> b.txt
  SET /A count+=1
)
```

It works well, printing the line number and the line content of the file a.txt and put the line in file b.txt

Unfortunately it crashes if I have really big lines (they are about 8K characters each).

Just for example I used just two lines of the big file:

```
0,0,0,0,0,1886,0,0,0,0,0,0,1883,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1888,0,0,0,0,0,0,1893,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1884,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,1891,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,1897,0,0,0,0,0,0,1889,0,0,0,0,0,1904,0,0,0,0,0,0,1905,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1910,0,0,0,0,0,0,1906,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1919,0,0,0,0,0,1922,0,0,0,0,0,0,1927,0,0,0,0,0,0,1925,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1941,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1940,0,0,0,0,0,1945,0,0,0,0,0,0,1947,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1949,0,0,0,0,0,1958,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1960,0,0,0,0,0,1975,0,0,0,0,0,0,1972,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1964,0,0,0,0,0,1981,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3467,0,0,0,0,0,0,3478,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3495,0,0,0,0,0,0,3493,0,0,0,0,0,0,3506,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3549,0,0,0,0,0,0,3554,0,0,0,0,0,0,3557,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3565,0,0,0,0,0,0,3574,0,0,0,0,0,0,3590,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3624,0,0,0,0,0,0,3671,0,0,0,0,0,0,3690,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3709,0,0,0,0,0,0,3760,0,0,0,0,0,0,3806,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3824,0,0,0,0,0,0,3873,0,0,0,0,0,3915,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3941,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,906,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,788,0,0,0,0,0,773,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,756,0,0,0,0,0,0,747,0,0,0,0,0,737,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,730,0,0,0,0,0,0,724,0,0,0,0,0,0,714,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,710,0,0,0,0,0,0,706,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,647,0,0,0,0,0,636,0,0,0,0,0,0,626,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,624,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,617,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,612,0,0,0,0,0,0,600,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,583,0,0,0,0,0,573,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,567,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,561,0,0,0,0,0,556,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,0,551,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,552,0,0,0,0,550,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,541,0,0,0,0,0,533,0,0,0,0,0,0,523,0,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,0,510,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,512,0,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,516,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,521,0,0,0,0,0,0,521,0,0,0,0,0,0,521,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,0,520,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,517,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,506,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,503,0,0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,0,0,499,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,0,494,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,490,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,0,0,493,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,496,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,498,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,498,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,496,0,0,0,0,496,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,493,0,0,0,0,0,0,489,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,482,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,479,0,0,0,0,0,475,0,0,0,0,0,0,471,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,310,0,0,0,0,304,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,302,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,302,304,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,305,0,0,0,0,0,0,306,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,308,0,0,309,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,311,313,0,0,0,0,0,316,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,319,0,0,0,0,0,0,324,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,371,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,375,0,0,0,379,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,384,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,501,0,0,0,0,0,505,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,507,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,509,0,0,0,0,0,0,512,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,0,0,522,0,0,0,0,0,0,528,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,534,0,0,0,0,0,0,542,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,550,0,0,0,0,0,555,0,0,0,0,0,0,558,0,0,0,0,0,562,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,565,0,0,0,0,0,0,569,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,570,0,0,0,0,0,575,0,0,0,0,0,0,584,0,0,0,0,0,0,592,0,0,0,0,0,0,602,0,0,0,0,0,0,612,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,622,0,0,0,0,0,0,629,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,569,0,0,0,0,0,0,561,0,0,0,0,0,559,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,552,0,0,0,0,0,550,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,550,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,552,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,0,557,0,0,0,0,0,0,561,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,564,0,0,0,0,571,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,577,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,588,0,0,0,0,604,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,881,0,0,0,0,0,0,948,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,967,0,0,0,0,0,0,971,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,972,0,0,0,0,0,979,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,998,0,0,0,0,0,0,1017,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,1036,0,0,0,0,1226,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1263,0,0,0,0,0,1293,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1331,0,0,0,0,0,0,1381,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1422,0,0,0,0,0,1594,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1597,0,0,0,0,0,0,1587,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1576,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1322,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1040,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1032,0,0,0,0,0,0,1045,0,0,0,0,0,0,1052,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1045,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1043,0,0,0,0,0,0,1043,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1038,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,1036,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1032,0,0,0,0,0,0,1031,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1022,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,1025,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1025,0,0,0,0,0,0,1024,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1020,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1029,0,0,0,0,0,1034,0,0,0,0,0,0,1030,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1031,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1030,0,0,0,0,0,0,1027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1199,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1134,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1109,0,0,0,0,0,0,1099,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1092,0,0,0,0,0,0,1096,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1086,0,0,0,0,0,0,1100,0,0,0,0,0,0,1197,0,0,0,0,0,1384,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1334,0,0,0,0,0,0,1283,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1235,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1192,0,0,0,0,0,0,1151,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1113,0,0,0,0,0,0,1075,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1043,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1016,0,0,0,0,0,0,982,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,955,0,0,0,0,0,0,934,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,908,0,0,0,0,0,0,886,0,0,0,0,0,0,863,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,844,0,0,0,0,0,0,823,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,806,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,789,0,0,0,0,0,774,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,756,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,742,0,0,0,0,0,0,729,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,715,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,702,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,690,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,679,0,0,0,0,0,0,669,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,658,0,0,0,0,0,0,646,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,637,0,0,0,0,0,630,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,620,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,612,0,0,0,0,0,603,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,596,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,589,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,581,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,573,0,0,0,0,568,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,561,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,544,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,538,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,533,0,0,0,0,0,0,528,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,522,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,518,0,0,0,0,0,513,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,509,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,505,0,0,0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,493,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,489,0,0,0,0,0,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,482,0,0,0,0,0,480,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,476,0,0,0,0,0,0,473,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,470,0,0,0,0,0,468,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,464,0,0,0,0,0,0,462,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,460,0,0,0,0,0,457,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,455,0,0,0,453,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,452,0,0,0,0,0,0,449,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,448,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,446,0,0,0,0,0,444,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,444,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,441,0,0,0,0,441,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,439,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,438,0,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,0,436,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,430,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,435,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,435,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,436,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,439,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,439,0,0,0,0,0,441,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,443,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,444,0,0,0,0,0,0,445,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,446,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,448,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,450,0,0,0,0,0,452,0,0,0,0,453,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,457,0,0,0,0,0,0,459,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,460,0,0,0,0,0,462,0,0,0,0,0,0,465,0,0,0,0,0,0,468,0,0,0,0,0,470,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,473,0,0,0,0,0,475,0,0,0,0,0,478,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,480,0,0,0,0,0,0,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,487,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,490,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,498,0,0,0,0,503,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,506,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,516,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,0,0,523,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,528,0,0,0,0,0,535,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,537,0,0,0,0,543,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,560,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,564,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,570,0,0,0,0,0,0,577,0,0,0,0,582,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,591,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,597,0,0,0,0,0,604,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,611,0,0,0,0,0,619,0,0,0,0,0,0,628,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,636,0,0,0,0,0,645,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,654,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,664,0,0,0,0,0,675,0,0,0,0,0,0,684,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,675,0,0,0,0,0,695,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,700,0,0,0,0,0,0,709,0,0,0,0,0,0,722,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,755,0,0,0,0,772,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,769,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,781,0,0,0,0,799,0,0,0,0,0,0,816,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,835,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,850,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,873,0,0,0,0,0,0,892,0,0,0,0,0,0,915,0,0,0,0,0,0,942,0,0,0,0,0,0,965,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,992,0,0,0,0,0,0,1018,0,0,0,0,0,0,1048,0,0,0,0,0,0,1082,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1117,0,0,0,0,0,1153,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1194,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1233,0,0,0,0,0,1285,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1332,0,0,0,0,0,0,1384,0,0,0,0,0,0,1435,0,0,0,0,0,0,1509,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1562,0,0,0,0,0,1693,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1775,0,0,0,0,0,0,1863,0,0,0,0,0,0,1929,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1931,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1925,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1914,0,0,0,0,0,1910,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1911,0,0,0,0,0,0,1896,0,0,0,0,0,0,1907,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,1887,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1893,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,1882
0,1892,0,0,0,0,0,0,1893,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1885,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1887,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1889,0,0,0,0,0,0,1890,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1889,0,0,0,0,0,0,1887,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1891,0,0,0,0,0,0,1893,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1897,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1895,0,0,0,0,0,0,1911,0,0,0,0,0,0,1910,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1919,0,0,0,0,0,0,1921,0,0,0,0,0,0,1927,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1925,0,0,0,0,0,0,1928,0,0,0,0,0,0,1935,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1932,0,0,0,0,0,0,1949,0,0,0,0,0,0,1955,0,0,0,0,0,0,1960,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1963,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1971,0,0,0,0,0,0,1973,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1976,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1998,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3458,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3476,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3485,0,0,0,0,0,0,3498,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3508,0,0,0,0,0,0,3537,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3547,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3558,0,0,0,0,0,0,3557,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3581,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3593,0,0,0,0,0,0,3638,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3682,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3733,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3736,0,0,0,0,0,0,3779,0,0,0,0,0,0,3807,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3830,0,0,0,0,0,3885,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3935,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,790,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,777,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,761,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,746,0,0,0,0,0,740,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,731,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,723,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,713,0,0,0,0,0,710,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,704,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,645,0,0,0,0,0,0,635,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,629,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,623,0,0,0,0,0,0,617,0,0,0,0,0,0,608,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,594,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,576,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,570,0,0,0,0,0,563,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,557,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,552,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,551,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,551,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,0,541,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,533,0,0,0,0,0,522,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,512,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,517,0,0,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,521,0,0,0,0,0,0,522,0,0,0,0,520,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,520,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,518,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,517,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,509,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,504,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,499,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,494,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,491,0,0,0,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,493,0,0,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,496,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,498,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,498,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,496,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,495,0,0,0,0,0,494,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,490,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,482,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,480,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,477,0,0,0,0,0,472,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,310,0,0,0,0,304,0,0,302,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,301,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,303,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,306,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,307,0,0,0,0,0,0,309,0,0,0,310,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,312,0,0,0,0,315,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,317,0,0,0,0,321,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,371,0,0,0,0,374,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,378,0,0,0,0,0,0,383,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,502,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,505,0,0,0,0,0,507,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,510,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,516,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,520,0,0,0,525,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,531,0,0,0,0,0,539,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,547,0,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,557,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,561,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,564,0,0,0,0,0,0,567,0,0,0,0,0,0,570,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,573,0,0,0,0,0,581,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,590,0,0,0,0,0,600,0,0,0,0,0,0,611,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,621,0,0,0,0,0,630,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,568,0,0,0,0,0,0,560,0,0,0,0,0,0,558,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,555,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,549,0,0,0,0,0,0,551,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,557,0,0,0,0,0,0,559,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,563,0,0,0,0,0,0,569,0,0,0,0,0,575,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,585,0,0,0,0,0,0,602,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,881,0,0,0,0,0,947,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,968,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,971,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,973,0,0,0,0,0,0,981,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1011,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1021,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1049,0,0,0,0,1234,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1278,0,0,0,0,0,0,1316,0,0,0,0,0,0,1357,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1404,0,0,0,0,0,0,1457,0,0,0,0,0,0,1598,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1593,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1582,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1041,0,0,0,0,0,0,1032,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1043,0,0,0,0,0,0,1055,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1044,0,0,0,0,0,0,1044,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1039,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1038,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1031,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,1026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,1030,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1029,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,1033,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1029,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1035,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1043,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,1028,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1030,0,0,0,0,1257,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1175,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1122,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1093,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1096,0,0,0,0,0,0,1081,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1095,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1179,0,0,0,0,1392,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1348,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1300,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1243,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1204,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1161,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1116,0,0,0,0,0,0,1081,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1044,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1015,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,981,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,956,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,927,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,905,0,0,0,0,0,880,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,857,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,837,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,817,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,800,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,782,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,750,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,737,0,0,0,0,0,722,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,709,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,694,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,683,0,0,0,0,0,0,670,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,659,0,0,0,0,0,0,649,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,638,0,0,0,0,0,630,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,622,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,612,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,603,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,596,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,588,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,580,0,0,0,0,0,0,572,0,0,0,0,0,0,567,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,559,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,547,0,0,0,0,0,0,541,0,0,0,0,0,536,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,530,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,525,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,521,0,0,0,0,0,515,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,511,0,0,0,0,506,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,502,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,494,0,0,0,0,0,0,490,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,487,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,483,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,481,0,0,0,0,0,0,476,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,473,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,470,0,0,0,0,0,0,467,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,464,0,0,0,0,0,0,462,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,459,0,0,0,0,0,0,456,0,0,0,0,0,454,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,452,0,0,0,0,0,451,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,448,0,0,0,0,0,447,0,0,0,0,0,446,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,444,0,0,0,0,0,442,0,0,0,0,0,441,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,439,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,438,0,0,0,0,0,438,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,436,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,431,0,0,0,0,0,432,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,434,0,0,0,0,435,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,435,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,437,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,438,0,0,0,0,0,439,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,441,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,442,0,0,0,0,0,444,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,445,0,0,0,0,0,0,447,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,448,0,0,0,0,0,449,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,452,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,453,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,457,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,458,0,0,0,0,460,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,462,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,466,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,468,0,0,0,0,0,471,0,0,0,0,0,0,473,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,476,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,479,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,483,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,486,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,490,0,0,0,0,0,492,0,0,0,0,0,497,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,501,0,0,0,0,505,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,509,0,0,0,0,514,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,519,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,522,0,0,0,0,0,0,527,0,0,0,0,0,0,533,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,537,0,0,0,0,0,543,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,548,0,0,0,0,553,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,560,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,566,0,0,0,0,0,0,571,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,578,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,584,0,0,0,0,592,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,598,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,604,0,0,0,0,0,0,614,0,0,0,0,0,623,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,631,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,639,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,649,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,658,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,671,0,0,0,0,0,0,682,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,691,0,0,0,0,706,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,699,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,708,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,719,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,736,0,0,0,0,0,810,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,768,0,0,0,0,0,0,781,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,798,0,0,0,0,0,0,816,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,836,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,854,0,0,0,0,0,0,873,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,898,0,0,0,0,0,920,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,948,0,0,0,0,0,0,971,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,998,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1063,0,0,0,0,0,1094,0,0,0,0,0,0,1136,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1170,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1218,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1268,0,0,0,0,0,1305,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1360,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1416,0,0,0,0,0,0,1482,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1559,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1676,0,0,0,0,0,1765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1852,0,0,0,0,0,0,1952,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1937,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1926,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1914,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1912,0,0,0,0,0,0,1911,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1893,0,0,0,0,0,1896,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1894,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1889,0,0,0,0,0,0,1900,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1891,0,0,0,0,0
```

Any particular settings to use to solve the problem?

Comment: See [Maximum Length of Command Line String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/). The command line length limit of 8192 characters (with terminating null byte) of Windows command processor cannot be easily worked around. It is necessary to use an executable which does not have this limitation. The simple solution would be using a PowerShell script for your task as PowerShell has no such line length limitation. Windows command processor is designed for executing commands and programs. It is not designed for file contents changing tasks. A VB script could be also used for this task.

Comment: Umm. OK. Thank you very much Mofi. I will do the job otherwise.