# Very long ffmpeg command due to drawtext commands for every second

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video of about 20 minutes length and want to show every second a different text using the drawtext filter. I used a java software to compute a very long ffmpeg command (more than 100,000 characters long). Pasting it into the PowerShell took a long time and then I got the error

```
Program 'ffmpeg.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt line:1 char:1
```

So the command is obviously too long. Can I somehow outsource it into an external file? I'm not looking for the subtitles filter instead of the drawtext filter because I'm using special functionalities of drawtext.

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string) the maximum length of a command line in Windows is roughly 8k, so you'll need to find some alternate way to do this. I don't think `ffmpeg` has a way to specify arbitrary command line options via a file (a common way to work around these kinds of constraints), but it would probably not be *too* hard to patch that in manually and use that special-built `ffmpeg` executable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary utf-8 text files containing the text (one file per `drawtext` filter instance) and specify them when calling `drawtext` filter with its `textfile` option instead of the `text` option. See [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1).

*Alternate Approach*

Break down the video into shorter segments so each ffmpeg command is within 8191-character limit. Then, use the `-f concat` demuxer with the `-c copy` muxer option to combine the output video segments.

Unfortunately, either approach requires creation of a tempdir to manage intermediate files but the latter will produce less number of them.

Comment: Can you make a little example? So I need 1200 different files?

Comment: Yes (to 1200 files). Create a temp dir, create these files, and recursively kill the temp dir. Pretty easy to do in Python, but I don't know PowerShell to give you an example.

Comment: Creating the files is no problem (I can do that in Java). But I'd like to see how the ffmpeg command looks then.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have the 8191-character limit. I tried to generate bigger and bigger commands and my biggest working command has 28878 characters.

Comment: I assume it's as simple as `ffmpeg ... -vf drawtext=textfile=tempdir/0.txt ...` if tempdir is within the working directory and `0.txt` being the file for the first second. With windows backslash dirsep, you may need to put the path in single quotes. (For the record, I knew of this option but never tested it myself...)

Comment: And `...` are the options and are not part of the text file? Then I don't save anything. The string is that long because of all the options. I'm using currently `drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='45.4 km/h':fontcolor=white:fontsize=200:box=1:boxcolor=black@0:boxborderw=50:x=40:y=h-th-25:shadowx=4:shadowy=4:enable='between(n,4125,4149)'`. So you see that the actual text is not the problem.

Comment: oh i see. then I'd try the alternate approach that I added to my post. Divide video into segments and copy-concatenate them

Comment: Yeah, but depending on the number of texts this might give very many segments. Maybe I want to place more control textes in the video. So in the end I might have lots of very short videos I have to concatenate.

Comment: Do you think there is a way using subtitles filter? So can I style the subtitles like when using the drawtext filter?

Comment: "lots of very short videos I have to concatenate." This shouldn't be too much issue as you can build `ffconcat` text file as you encode segments (at least to me). The concatenation will go pretty fast (should be bounded by your NVMe/SSD/HDD speed)

Comment: "subtitles" Look into SSA/ASS format. That format among the ones I've checked out in the past grants the most amount of format controls to user.

Comment: You're right. Concatenation doesn't take too much time. Nevertheless, I'm still looking for a better solution. My next idea: Is it possible to set the default font for ffmpeg? Then I could leave out a lot of characters for each text to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this (yet another) alternate approach as a separate answer because it is substantially different from the previous takes.

You can shorten the command line by prepending a [`sendcmd`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) filter in front of each `drawtext` filter. [The `drawtext` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-83) shows an example of using `sendcmd` to alter the text:

> `sendcmd=c='56.0 drawtext reinit fontsize=56\:fontcolor=green\:text=Hello\\ World'`

If you also check the `sendcmd` documentation, it lists the filename option:

> filename, f
>
> Set the filename of the commands to be read and sent to the other filters.

with an example:

> Specify a list of drawtext and hue commands in a file.
>
> ```
> # show text in the interval 5-10
> 5.0-10.0 [enter] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text=hello world',
>         [leave] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text=';
> ```
>
> A filtergraph allowing to read and process the above command list stored in a file test.cmd, can be specified with:
>
> ```
> sendcmd=f=test.cmd,drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='',hue
> ```

So, instead of using the `enable=between(start,end)` option, you can use a single `drawtext` filter in the graph and compose a command text file to instruct it what to do.

Comment: This sounds great. I have to test it!