# Pass file list to Mercurial 'hg add' command from text file

Tags: windows, command-line, mercurial

I'm attempting to add about 40k files to Mercurial using 'hg add' on Win 10.  Due to downstream constraints I need to split this up into chunks of 10k files for each add/commit, therefore I need to pass large lists of files to hg add.  However I'm hitting [Window's commandline argument character limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string).

Is there a way to pass file lists stored in a file to hg add?  AFAIK can't just use pipes as this is just reading the file and passing it as arguments.  I think hg would need to directly read the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using Mercurial's extensive pattern functionality and possibly file sets (see `hg help patterns` and `hg help filesets`).

One type of pattern that you can specify is the `listfile:` pattern, which takes a filename as an argument, which must contain a newline-separated list of patterns (which of course can be filenames).

So, you would first produce lists of the files in question, split up across several files. Let's assume they're called `files1.txt`, `files2.txt`, ...

Then you'd do the following:

```
hg add listfile:files1.txt
hg commit
hg add listfile:files2.txt
hg commit
...
```

If that by itself isn't sufficient, you can use file sets to further modify what files get added.

Comment: Thanks!  the listfile pattern seems promising, I'll report back when I get a chance to try it

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a direct answer to how to get hg to read from a list of files - but an alternative idea).

My thought is to use `hg addremove` instead of `add` since it already is designed to work in "batch".

From `hg addremove --help`:

> `hg addremove [OPTION]... [FILE]...`
>
> add all new files, delete all missing files
>
> ...
>
> options ([+] can be repeated):
>
> ```
>  -I --include PATTERN [+]   include names matching the given patterns
>  ...
>  -n --dry-run               do not perform actions, just print output
> ```

(some details omitted)

So a command like the following might work:

`hg addremove --include path\to\files\prefix*.*`

(The question doesn't have any specifics about filenames or paths to know more specifically how to structure the `include` details.)

This only marks the files for addition; it doesn't automatically commit. So you would be able to run this multiple times, varying the inclusion criteria, committing each time in multiple batches.

Also note that `hg commit` accepts a similar `--include` option. So alternately you could `addremove` 100% of your files in one go, and then issue multiple commits for only a portion of all the files each. For instance, just commit one directory at a time, or some other scheme that is easy to do and get under the 10K file limit.